# Count values in array and calculate top 4

Tags: php, csv

I have CSV list with team names in it (this is one row):

```
Teams
Red
Green | Red | Yellow
Red
Yellow | Green | Yellow
Red
Green
Yellow | Yellow | Red
Red
Green
Red
Yellow
```

I need to be able to count each individual color and count top 4 
and number of times they appear.

How can I do that? For example if i try using:

```
   $teams = file('count.csv');
   $count[] = (array_count_values($colors));
   print_r($count);
```

I get:

```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [Teams ] => 1 
   [Red ] => 5 [Green | Red | Yellow ] => 1 [Yellow | Green | Yellow ] => 1 [Green ] => 2      [Yellow | Yellow | Red ] => 1 [Yellow] => 1 ) )
```

Which is not very useful. And afrewards how could I compare the valies to one another to get top 4?

Any tricks known how to make this happen? Thank you in advance!

OK another try:

```
    $inputfile = 'count.csv';
    $inputHandle = fopen($inputfile, "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($inputHandle, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    $teams = $data[0];

    $teams = explode('|', $teams);

    }

    $count[] = (array_count_values($teams));
    print("<pre>".print_r($count, true)."</pre>");
```

I get

```
   Array
   (
     [0] => Array
       (
           [Yellow] => 1
       )

   )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try the function explode with delimiter |

Comment: $inputfile = 'count.csv';
        $inputHandle = fopen($inputfile, "r");
        
        while (($data = fgetcsv($inputHandle, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        
        $teams = $data[0];
        
        $teams = explode('|', $teams);
        
        }
        
        $count[] = (array_count_values($teams));
        print("<pre>".print_r($count, true)."</pre>");

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've got one row of data, with | as the delimiter.

Here's a very crude quick'n'dirty solution.

What I would do is first use `strpos()` and `substr()` to get the colors, and use a switch-case to increment counters for each color. To get the top 4, create an array to hold four strings, insert the first four colors, and then compare the remaining colors to each value in the array, overwriting values in the array if the color you're comparing has a higher count than any value in the array.

This sounds a bit confusing, so let me know if you'd like me to write some sample code demonstrating this.